# Convert date time to another format

Tags: c#, datetime-conversion

I am trying to convert a datetime of like 17 Dec 2019 19:13:14:850 to 17/12/2019 19:13 using the below code:

```
string dateTime = "17 Dec 2019 19:13:14:850";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTime,"dd:MM:yyyy hh:mm:ss:fff",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string s = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But getting error msg as:

> String was not recognized as valid date time.

Comment: `string s= dt.ToString(dd/MM/yyyy,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );` should be `string s= dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );` you are missing the quotes.

Comment: Please examine the value you are parsing closely. The only separators between the date parts are spaces, not colons.

Answer (score 7):

The format of your initial string is actually:
`"dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss:fff"`

`MM` gives you the month number, whereas `MMM` gives you the abbreviated month name. Also, since you're using ParseExact, you needed to get rid of the `:`s in the date portion, because they are not present in your string.

Then, if you're wanting to get it to `17/12/2019 19:13` the format will be `"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm"` - yours is also not quoted, but I will assume that's a typo in the original post

**Edit**: as the other answerer pointed out, you should be using `HH` instead of `hh` in both of these cases, as the time format is 24 hours, so:

`"dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff"` and `"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"`

Answer (score 1):

The small `hh` is causing the problem here as you are parsing a 24-hour format.

The values should be `dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff` and `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm`

Try the following

```
string dateTime = "17 Dec 2019 19:13:14:850";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTime, "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string s = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```